# Unable to update system app

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have been trying to update the system apps on my android phone, where in I get an error mentioning that the application which I'm downloading can't be installed. (Error code :- 104)

When I searched this problem on the internet, most solutions say *"You have to root your cell phone and then try to update/install the respective application on your phone."*

As I don't want to root my phone, is there any better solution to solve this problem instead of rooting my phone ?

And when I tried to install updated .apk file externally it shows error
[image]

Comment: On the 104 error, [Google support suggests](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/mbt7AuN3EK4) to follow the [I can't download from or load the Google Play Store troubleshooting guide link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/troubleshooter/6241347) (switch off the device, wait a few minutes, switch it on and try again). Could you please verify whether it works for you?

Comment: No I am not getting it, As you are saying i tried all the step's which is given by play store and still I am not able to update applications

Answer (score 0):

Click on settings > backup and reset > factory reset then say yes to clean your phone.

If you try to factory reset your phone, this will do your phone automatically update your phone with initial version of your applications.

Then try to update your respective built-in application from play store, it will solve your solution.

Comment: The OP wants to update stock apps via Play Store.

Comment: If you factory-reset your device, that doesn't "automatically update your phone with initial version of your applications" but simply remove all updates, configurations, etc. – see our [factory-reset tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) for details. As a side-effect it will also clear the cache of Google Play Store, which *might* solve this issue (or not); but that's like killing a fly with atomics if you don't even know where the fly sits.

Comment: Removing all updates, configurations, etc also means the same which is nothing but it brings back to initial version.

Answer (score 0):

Open App Info of Google Play, clear cache and/or data and try updating the app again, should help in resolving that error.

If it doesn't help, and you require the update urgently, try downloading an APK file of that particular app, enable "Unknown sources" in Settings > Security, and open the downloaded APK using PackageInstaller. A good source to find the APK file of the app is [APKMirror](http://apkmirror.com).

Comment: I updated the question and added an image of showing error when I tried to install updated .apk file

Comment: @VijayGupta basically that means you already have the updated app.

Comment: No I checked application version that was an older verson, whose update is showing in play store

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to take a build of apk and sign with google with the system/laptop from which you take a base apk uploaded in google play store.

Because conflict in signature(SHA) key of system will lead to this error while updating the application.

you can get system SHA key using below terminal command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```